# Adding Google Drive support to Android project

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-play-services

I want to include Google Drive support in my application, using Android Studio 3.0.1

I have the following entries in my app' build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:11.6.0'
```

When I try to do a Gradle build I get the following error:

[image]

When clicking on "Install Repository and sync project" I then get the following error:

[image]

Is the syntax of my dependencies section wrong?

[Google](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#Install) shows use of the `implementation` directive instead of `compile` but doesn't work for me either.

I've tried changing the play-services-drive line to this:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:+'
```

but then I get a load of resource errors that I've never seen before. This project built and ran before I started trying to add the Google imports below:

[image]

Errors:

[image]

Comment: **Never** use `+` as the version. All Google services need to be the same version. And if all you want is drive, `play-services-drive:11.6.0` is the only dependency needed

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks. I tried using the version you quoted but it started telling me it couldn't find it so I just used '+' to try and shut it up. I'll take your advice though.

Comment: @cricket_007 Once I got rid of those '+' dependencies, those resource errors went away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did follow step 4?

> If you receive an error, check that your top-level build.gradle contains a reference to the google() repo or to maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }.

You would put this in your top-level `build.gradle` file like so:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Google's Play Services are often horribly documented. You should consult [their demo project](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos) as a better reference as to how to use the APIs (that's where the sample code is from). Hope that helps!

Comment: No, I didn't follow that step - even now I have no idea where I'm supposed to put this in my build.gradle file. It isn't very clear.

Comment: Just trying to change my Project's build.gradle to: allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}  ..maybe this will work when it eventually finishes Gradle sync..